# How to parse multiple cookies with same using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Can anyone tell me how to parse the following response from the server using **JSOUP**

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=osfveluimtjhkctqs34gsdafu5; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: boot[uid]=nwbh%2FtiM4p05%2BMPASufbYLa8tKwkDbZenBreisH2Vd0%3D; expires=Mon, 03-Nov-2014 11:48:03 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=sm44686g967qf4e21mogbjucf6; path=/
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=04h16usgeatii00gt85rdgbup1; path=/
```

Here im getting cookies "PHPSESSID" 3 times .
when im trying to parse

```
Connection.Response doc = Jsoup.connect("///")......execute();
System.out.println(doc.cookie("PHPSESSID"));
System.out.println(doc.cookies());
```

either way i was not able to get all those cookies
plz help me ...

Comment: Hi, Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: Hi @elysch, i did'nt get any solution, it an issue with the server side.